# Selenium NoClassDefFoundError with Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was able to use the following dependency just fine:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I try to go to 4.1.0 with the following, I get an error:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

With the error:

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/FindsById] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.FindsById
```

I also get `ClassNotFoundException: "PortProber"`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I have to import another Maven dependency?

I am using the docker container:

```
ARG CHROME_VERSION=96.0.4664.45-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

## ChromeDriver

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=96.0.4664.45
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_PORT 4444
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS "127.0.0.1"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE ''
EXPOSE 4444
EXPOSE 5005
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
# For Testing
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `ARG CHROME_VERSION=96.0.4664.45-1` and not  _`ARG CHROME_VERSION=96.0.4664.45`_

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB yes I am certain the chrome arg is correct - see https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable .

Comment: Ahh, didn't consider _`ubuntu`_

Answer (score 0):

These classes are deprecated in selenium v4, please use the alternative or use the 3.x version,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to import more classes. Importing the following works:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```